# How to find supported version of the flutter app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

How to find minimum android version witch flutter app support? Can anyone please provide witch file it have and location of it?

Comment: Can check https://pub.dev/packages/package_info

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on

What devices and OS versions does Flutter run on?

-Mobile operating systems: Android Jelly Bean, v16, 4.1.x or newer, and iOS 8 or newer.

-Mobile hardware: iOS devices (iPhone 4S or newer) and ARM Android devices.

-Flutter supports building ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled libraries for x86_64, armeabi-v7a, and arm64-v8a.

-Apps built for ARMv7 or ARM64 run fine (using ARM emulation) on many x86 Android devices.